# How to fix error in code generated by Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using code first migrations with an existing database. I used the reverse engineering feature to generate all the initial entities. However, the database was not well designed and one of the tables did not have a primary key designated. Apparently Entity Framework did its best to infer the primary key and didn't get it right. It looks like it decided to make two fields a compound primary key.

I want to actually remove one of the fields that it mistakenly thinks is part of the primary key and it's resulting in errors.

Here is the original schema of the table when the entity was created for it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [The_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Field_1] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Field_2] [bigint] NULL,
    [Field_3] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Field_4] [datetime] NULL,
    [Field_5] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table1_F5]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Field_5]
GO
```

`The_ID` should have been designated as the primary key but as you can see it was not. Here is class the Visual Studio generated:

```
public partial class Table1
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long The_ID { get; set; }

    public byte[] Field_1 { get; set; }

    public long? Field_2 { get; set; }

    public byte[] Field_3 { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Field_4 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public bool Field_5 { get; set; }
}
```

It apparently decided to make `The_ID` and `Field_5` into a compound primary key. At least that's how I'm interpreting this code. Now, I actually need to remove `Field_5` from the table. I created an migration to do this, but since Entity Framework thinks its part of a primary key its doing weird things like dropping the primary key and re-adding it, which is resulting in errors. Here is the generated migration code:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Table1", "The_ID", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1", "The_ID");
    DropColumn("dbo.Table1", "Field_5");
}
```

Running this results in the following error:

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Table1]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 'PK_dbo.Table1' is not a constraint.

So how do I get myself out of this mess?

I tried removing the `[Key]` attributes from `The_ID` and `Field_5` and creating a dummy migration using

> Add-Migration dummy -IgnoreChanges

with the thought that I could then add the `[Key]` attribute back to `The_ID` and remove `Field_5` but it won't let me create a migration unless at least one field is designated with the `[Key]` attribute. But if I do that to get the dummy migration in place then I can't do it in a real migration so I'm not able to actually designate The_ID as the primary key using code first migrations.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the desired result. Whould you like the Fild_5 to be droped and a Primary key on the_id being created?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Table without Primary Key in you Database EntityFramework will interpret every not nullable column in the table as part of the Primary Key.

In this case you could just remove the first two lines from the generated Migration, because there is no primary key to drop. EntityFramework just does not know about this fact.

```
public override void Up()
{
    //DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1");
    //AlterColumn("dbo.Table1", "The_ID", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Table1", "The_ID");
    DropColumn("dbo.Table1", "Field_5");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I ended up doing. I just wasn't sure if modifying an automatically generated migration was okay to do. But I guess it's just code and it's not like it's going to change unless I explicitly tell the system to regenerate it.

Comment: Changing the migrations is perfectly fine. Sometimes you are supposed to do so. If you rename a Property/Column Add-Migration might create a DropColumn/AddColumn migration. Manually change it to RenameColumn. Also adding some additional indexes can be done manually. The generated Migration is more or less only a suggestion